# Multilevel Structural Equation Model - Meta analysis - STATA gsem

Tags: stata, multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis, structural-equation-modeling

I am quite familiar with mixed effects (multilevel models) in meta analyses.
Now, I want to do a **mixed effects (multilevel) meta analysis structural equation model (MASEM)** with *STATA* and the *gsem* package because my data format is long.

My data look like:
`id studyId performance education moderator1 moderator2`
 `1   1       -0.4        0.1       1           0`
 `2   1        0.2        0.1       0           1`
 `3   2        0.5        0.3       0           1`
 `4   3       -0.1        0.4       1           0`
 `5   3       -0.6        0.4       1           0`

**performance:** Firm-Performance, correlation coefficients (Fisher z transformed)
**moderator1-moderator2:** My moderator variables, have some nusisance variables as well but do not display it here.
**education:** Pre-dominant education level in a certain country

All variables are weighted by w = fisher z variance + tau

I want to model primary study effects nested in primary studies (results grouped in the related study).

```
gsem (performance <- moderator1 moderator2 education M1[id]@1 M2[id>studyId]@1)  
(moderator1 <- education M3[id]@1 M4[id>studyId]@1)  
(moderator2 <- education M5[id]@1 M6[id>studyId]@1),  
Latent(M1 M2 M3 M4 M5)  
cov(e.performance M1[id]*M2[id>studyId])
cov(M3[id]*M4[id>studyId])
cov(M5[id]*M6[id>studyId])
```

I am not sure about the specification of the model in *STATA*.
1. Did I model the covariances in a correct way?
2. @1 means I normalize the latent variable. What alternatives do I have?
3. Is it enough just to model the error term (e.performance) of the dependent variable performance or do I have to model all variables there?

Thank you very much for your support :-)

Comment: The [metaSEM package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=metaSEM) in R provides better support to meta-analytic structural equation modeling. If you really want to do it in STATA, you may contact [Tom Palmer](http://www.lancaster.ac.uk/maths/about-us/people/tom-palmer). Tom and I are working on a paper on implementing MASEM in STATA.

Comment: Dear Mike, thank you very much for your answer. I sent you an Email. Would be great to receive an answer.